# Show the first error only

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am using code igniter form_validation class to perform a number of validations, since codeigniter validates all the fields and then shows a list of all the errors, I need to restrict this to show only the first error that occurred.

Eg.

If I have 2 (email, message) fields with the `required` validation in place, and if I were to leave both fields blank. I need codeigniter to show only the error The Email Field is required.

Comment: Would be best if you add some code to explain better what your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge CI doesn't come with this out of the box, but it's easy enough to implement:

Firstly, (if you don't have this file already) create the file `MY_Form_validation.php` in **application/libraries/** with the following:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }
}
```

Then add the following method to that class:

```
 /**
 * First Error
 *
 * Returns the first error messages as a string, wrapped in the error delimiters
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  str
 */
public function first_error($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
{
    // No errrors, validation passes!
    if (count($this->_error_array) === 0)
    {
        return '';
    }

    if ($prefix == '')
    {
        $prefix = $this->_error_prefix;
    }

    if ($suffix == '')
    {
        $suffix = $this->_error_suffix;
    }

    // Generate the error string
    $str = '';
    foreach ($this->_error_array as $val)
    {
        if ($val != '')
        {
            return $prefix.$val.$suffix."\n";
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

This way you'll be able to access this with `$this->form_validation->first_error()`

Alternatively, you can create a helper function similar to `validation_errors()` by (if the file doesn't exist) creating a file called `MY_form_helper.php` in **application/helpers/**

and then adding the following code:

```
/**
 * First Validation Error String
 *
 * Returns the first error associated with a form submission.  This is a helper
 * function for the form validation class.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('first_validation_error'))
{
    function first_validation_error($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
    {
        if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
        {
            return '';
        }

        return $OBJ->first_error($prefix, $suffix);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!